# VB.NET ComboBox Verify if Value Exists

Tags: vb.net, combobox, vb.net-2010, verify

I am currently working on an application that was coded in VB. I am making modifications and adding features to it.

The issue I have is that I want to run a verification check for the ComboBox based on if the value exists before I attempt to select it.

The combo box is populated from a sql query with a dictionary data source

```
Dim TimerComboSource As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
TimerComboSource.Add(varSQLReader("ID").ToString, varSQLReader("Name").ToString)
'Binds the values to the comboboxes
cmbTimer.DataSource = New BindingSource(TimerComboSource, Nothing)
cmbTimer.DisplayMember = "Value"
cmbTimer.ValueMember = "Key"
```

I select a value from a different ComboBox which is populated with a different SQL Query/SQL Table.

When I select the second ComboBox value, the table it comes from contains the ID of the first ComboBox. I want to verify if the Value Exists in the first ComboBox before I select it.

The following does not work:

```
If cmbTechnician.Items.Contains(varSQLReader("Tech_ID").ToString) Then
    cmbTechnician.SelectedValue = varSQLReader("Tech_ID").ToString
End If
```

Is there a specific way in VB to make this work without it being overly complicated? The other work around would to make a more complicated SQL query but I rather not do that if there's a simpler way.

Comment: You can always cast the `DataSource` of the `BindingSource` back to `Dictionary(Of String, String)` and use `dict.ContainsKey`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a `BindingSource` on a Dictionary, you should use the `DataSource` to determine of things exist.  If you tried to add to `cmbTimer.Items` or delete from it directly, you'd get an error telling you to use the `DataSource`.  So do the same for checking if something exists (dont use a dictionary with local scope):

```
' form or class level collection
Private cboSource As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

cboSource.Add("red", "red")
cboSource.Add("blue", "blue")
cboSource.Add("green", "green")

cbo.DataSource = New BindingSource(cboSource, Nothing)
cbo.DisplayMember = "Value"
cbo.ValueMember = "Key"

If cbo.Items.Contains("red") Then
    Console.Beep()     ' wont hit
End If

If cboSource.ContainsValue("red") Then
    Console.Beep()     ' hits!
End If
```

The suggestion in comments suggests casting the `DataSource` of the `BindingSource` back to dictionary:

```
Dim tempBS As BindingSource = CType(cbo.DataSource, BindingSource)
Dim newCol As Dictionary(Of String, String) = CType(tempBS.DataSource, Dictionary(Of String, String))

If newCol.ContainsValue("red") Then
    Console.Beep()     ' hits!
End If
```

It is easier and more direct to retain a reference to the dictionary, but recreating it will work.

Comment: This is partially right. However I wanted to verify the ID/Value of the combo box or the key of the dictionary. Not the Item/Text of the combo box or value of the dictionary. In other words this works if you do newCol.ContainsKey. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here are another way =>

```
 If cmbTechnician.FindString(varSQLReader("Tech_ID").ToString) <= -1 Then
         'Do Not Exist 
 End If
```

This will find the display member and will return an index of the row if there exist value, otherwise will return -1.

More Info are here=>[ComboBox.FindString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxyt1t12(v=vs.110).aspx)